# jQuery print loop from JSON API

Tags: jquery, json, api, loops

So I'm pulling specific data from an API. And I can get what I need to `console.log()` just how I want it to appear, but when I try to insert the data into a HTML `div` tag I catch an error.

index.html file

```
   <html>
   <body>        
   <div class="results"></div>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
   integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

main.js file

```
    var divContents = document.getElementById("results");
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'https://api.github.com/events');

    request.onload = function(){
        var selectedData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++){
            console.log(`Username: ${selectedData[i].actor.login} 
            Type: ${selectedData[i].type}
            Repo Name: ${selectedData[i].repo.name}`);
      }
    };

   request.send();
```

When I change `console.log` to `$('.results').text()`, it doesn't work.
I have JQuery tied to the HTML.

Comment: How are you trying to insert it with `$('.divclass').text()`? Also, have you ensured you have a valid HTML target?

Comment: I have tried changing .text to .html but it only prints the first object

Comment: the HMTL target: <div class="results"></div>

Comment: Please show the **exact code** you are attempting to use. Also show your HTML. When does this JavaScript execute?

Comment: "when I try to insert the data into a HTML div I catch an error". What is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using an odd mix of jQuery and vanilla JS.

Also, using `.text()` would overwrite the text content of your element with each iteration. You probably want to *append* data.

Why not just use all the jQuery tools available to you.

There's [`jQuery.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) for making the AJAX request and [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) for adding content to elements. You can even pass an array of data to *append*. I'd recommend *mapping* the fetched data to the format you want.

```
$.getJSON('https://api.github.com/events').done(data => {
  $('.results').append(data.slice(0, 25).map(datum =>
    `Username: ${datum.actor.login}\nType: ${datum.type}\nRepo Name: ${datum.repo.name}`
  ))
})
```